# How to pass API data value into the sfslider range in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, syncfusion

How to pass the API data value into the sfslider if I pass the static value to the slider it can be draggable. But if I give the API data value directly it can drag but not update the new value and return to the API response value position.

I saw some of the solutions they said declare a static value outside of a widget, it works fine. But I need to use API values, How to do it? Somebody can help me!

```
 double _value = 40.0;
                
                @override
                Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                  return MaterialApp(
                      home: Scaffold(
                          body: Center(
                           
               FutureBuilder(
               future: propertycall(),
               // ignore: missing_return
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return SfSlider(
                   shouldAlwaysShowTooltip: true,
                   activeColor: secondarycolor,
                   min: snapshot.data["set-parameters"]["mortgage_interest_rate"]["min_value"],
                   max: snapshot.data["set-parameters"]["mortgage_interest_rate"]["max_value"],
                    value: _value,       //issue occur here 
    // value:snapshot.data["set-parameters"]["mortgage_interest_rate"]
    //["default_value"]    
                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                            
             interval: snapshot.data["set-parameters"]["mortgage_interest_rate"]
                          ["steps_value"], 
             showTicks: false,
             showLabels: false,
             enableTooltip: true,
             numberFormat: NumberFormat(),                                             
                                                                    
             onChanged: (new_value) {
                  setState(() {
                   _value = new_value; // issues!!
    
         //API value working but not able to drag slider, 
         //if I give static value from outside of a widget it works                                                  
                                                          
        //  _value=snapshot.data["set-parameters"]["mortgage_interest_rate"]
    //["default_value"]  
                                                          
                                                                                                                                                        },
);
  },

 ),
},
},
);       
   ),
          ),
                     
                  );
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `_value` nullable and use it when not null.

```
double? _value = null;

...

value: _value ?? snapshot.data["set-parameters"]["mortgage_interest_rate"]
```

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed the code snippet and found that in the sample you set the static value from the API, and it does not get changed. It is always a static one, this is the reason for the point not getting dragged. For this, you just need to update the pointer value in API which is got from the onChanged callback and rebuild the slider control. Then only the point gets moved otherwise it will stay at the initial position and did not get dragged.